# Reduction formula for $\int \frac { x ^ n } { \sqrt { 1 - x ^ 2 } } \ \mathrm d x $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, reduction-formula

I'm struggling to go any further. Anyone have any hints?

$$ I _ n = \int \frac { x ^ n } { \sqrt { 1 - x ^ 2 } } \ \mathrm d x $$

I used integration by parts where I differentiated $ x ^ n $, but it resulted in an $ \arcsin x $ term which didn't get me anywhere.

$$ u = x ^ n $$
$$ v = \arcsin x $$
$$ \mathrm d v = \frac { \mathrm d x } { \sqrt { 1 - x ^ 2 } } $$
$$ I _ n = \int u \ \mathrm d v = u v - \int v \ \mathrm d u = x ^ n \arcsin x - ( n - 1 ) \int x ^ { n - 1 } \arcsin x \ \mathrm d x $$

Comment: Please typeset searchable equations using *MathJax*.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to ask. Could you please provide more context and additional details?

Comment: Please use [this mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/72031) designed for beginners and type all the equations in your question.

Comment: when you put n=0,1,2,3,4... etc did u see a pattern?

Answer (score 3):

$$I_n=\int\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

Let $x=\sin y\implies dx=\cos y \,dy$

$$I_n=\int\sin^ny \,dy$$

which has a well known [reduction formula](https://youtu.be/y-9iRPENXoU)

Comment: You should add a space between $y$ and $dy$.

Comment: but how can I relate it back to I_n

Comment: @Crystal after finding $I_n$ in terms of $y$ just plug back $y=\arcsin x$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yes sir working on it

Answer (score 0):

Integrate by parts as follows
\begin{align}
 \int \frac { x ^ n } { \sqrt { 1 - x ^ 2 } } d x 
&= -\int \frac { x ^{n-1} } { (1 - x ^ 2 )^{\frac{n-1}2}} d \left(\frac{(1-x^2)^{\frac n2}}n\right)\\
&=-\frac1n \frac{x^{n-1}}{\sqrt { 1 - x ^ 2 } }+ \frac{n-1}n\int \frac { x ^ {n-2} } { \sqrt { 1 - x ^ 2 } } d x \\
\end{align}
hence the reduction formula

$$I_n = -\frac1n \frac{x^{n-1}}{\sqrt { 1 - x ^ 2 } }+ \frac{n-1}n I_{n-2}$$